# Python - How to read list values from config file (INI) using python configParser

Tags: python, csv, configparser

i am trying to read some header values from config file in python while creating CSV.

Working Python file:

```
headers = ['Column1','Column2','Column3']
...
writer.writerow(header)
...
```

**Using Config:**
**text.conf**

```
[CSV]
headers = 'Column1','Column2','Column3'
```

**Python file**

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(text.conf)
header = config['CSV'].get('headers')
```

**But my csv file looks something like this,**

```
',C,o,l,u,m,n,1,',",",',C,o,l,u,m,n,2,',",",',C,o,l,u,m,n,3,'
```

**Expected:**

```
Column1,Column2,Column3
```

Comment: The value of `header` is `"'Column1','Column2','Column3'"`, you need to process that further for the output you expect.

Comment: From the docs: "Config parsers provide option value getters that perform type conversion. By default ``getint``(), ``getfloat``(), and ``getboolean``() are implemented." If you want to support a `getlistofstrings`, you must define it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting a string object and not a list. You can either process the string to a list

**Ex:**

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(text.conf)
header = [i.strip("'") for i in config['CSV'].get('headers').split(",")]
```

---

Or add `[]` --> `headers = ['Column1','Column2','Column3']` to the config file and use the `ast` module to convert it to a list

**Ex:**

```
headers = ['Column1','Column2','Column3']
print(ast.literal_eval(config['CSV']['headers']))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot folks. i did this, header = config['CSV'].get('headers').split(",") and config file has headers = Column1,Column2,Column3